# how to validate the facebook ID of a user to prevent from re-submitting again

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, validation

I have a picture contest using php which allows you to enter to upload or enter to vote. It also only allow one facebook user to upload one picture to the event at most.

How can I validate their facebook ID with MySQL data, such that the same user who already submitted once (according to the fbID) is not able to click the enter contest button again and when clicked, a msg box will pop out saying "You have already submitted once"?

Hope you guys will give suggestions. Thanks and appreciated all of your time for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store the Facebook user ID alongside the photo submission in your database.

I assume you'll have a table that contains the photo data; create a new field to store the Facebook user ID too. Then, when the user visits your app or whatever, check if their ID is already in the database. If so, don't give them the upload form but an error message; if not, allow them to upload.

**EDIT:** Check out [Facebook's SDK](http://www.github.com/facebook/php-sdk). There should be example's on there to fetch the details of the user viewing your app's page, which includes Facebook ID. You can then use that in your script.

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo "<script>top.location.href='$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

// if we're here, the user has successfully authenticated
// you now have access to their profile in $user_profile

$userId = intval($user_profile['id']);

// logic goes here to query database and check if $userId
// has already been used to submit a photo or not
```

Comment: Hi martin, yeap I do have a field in mySQL to store the facebook user ID which is called "facebookID". I understand the flow of how am i going to check it but the problem is i'm not really a good coder and all the if else statement that i tried turn out to be not working well so could you please show me a working example of how i could do it so i could reference it as well in the future if i ever encounter such task again ? Many thanks for replying and sorry for the bother.

Comment: just a note: the hidden fbID field which contains the value=<?php echo $me['id']?> is how i secretly take their fbID. Once again, thanks alot

Comment: You shouldn't need to drop their ID on the page, as they can then just use Web Inspector to change it to impersonate someone else when submitting your form.

Comment: I guess I should explain a little first. The codes that you edited up there, I already have it stored in one of the php files called fbmain.php. The flow goes like this: e.g A new user goes to my app and clicked on "Enter Contest" button. After that he filled up the form and submit successfully. So, his record is already inserted in my database. When he is redirect to the main page and tried to clicked the "Enter Contest" button, there will be a validation saying that he has already submitted once and therefore could not submit again.

Comment: Therefore, what I truly need is the if.. else statement on my php page such that it validates the facebook ID of that account accessing my app with the data stored in mySQL. Then if the facebook ID of that user could not be found on mySQL database, allow access when button is clicked, else, show error msg and block him from entereing. By the way, appreciate your time to enter the script up there.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just do the database look-up straight away. There's nothing more annoying than filling out a form only to be told I've wasted my time. Therefore, after you've authenticated, hit the database and check if the ID has already been inserted with a simple SQL `SELECT` query.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your quick reply all these times. I have done it using your way :D Thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to authenticate the user and grab the FB cookie.

See the documentation [on the FB developer site](http://developers.facebook.com).

Once you have the id, you can pull it from the db and use it to check if the user has submitted or not.